# Put message async on WebSphere MQ queue

Tags: java, asynchronous, ibm-mq, put

I am trying to put persistent messages onto a WebSphere MQ queue, however these need to be async puts.  The only way that I seem to be able to get async working is if the messages are non persistent (by this I mean that the `putSuccessCount` equals number of messages put on the `MQAsyncStatus`, all other times it is zero). The code below outlines what I am trying to do:

```
import com.ibm.mq.MQAsyncStatus;
import com.ibm.mq.MQDestination;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants;

public class MQPutTest extends TestCase{

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MQPutTest.class);

    public void testPut() throws Exception{

        Hashtable<String, Object> props = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        props.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "my_channel");
        props.put(MQConstants.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414);
        props.put(MQConstants.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "localhost");

        String qManager = "my_queue_manager"; 
        MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, props);

        int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF;

        MQDestination queue = qMgr.accessQueue("my_queue", openOptions);

        MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
        pmo.options = MQConstants.MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE;

        MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
        message.format = MQConstants.MQFMT_STRING;
        message.writeString("test message");
        queue.put(message, pmo);

        queue.close();
        MQAsyncStatus asyncStatus = qMgr.getAsyncStatus();
        qMgr.disconnect();
    }
}
```

I am attributing the performance increase I see with a large number of messages to the fact that the queue is set to non persistent rather than the messages being put async.  I have set the default put response type to Asynchronous in the queue extended properties in MQ explorer bu this has no effect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Messages send in the background are not persisted because they can be lost if your application stops before the message is sent.  The only way to know a message has been persisted is to wait for it to be accepted in a recoverable way (usually written to disk on the server)

Comment: Thanks, so is it possible to use fire and forget on persistent queues?  What I want to do is send messages to a persistent queue so they survive a restart, but not wait for the queue manager to respond back with each PUT, I just want to throw messages at the queue manager but don't need to know if they make it onto the queue or not for each message. I may use the MQAsyncStatus to reconcile the numbers after each batch of messages.  This is purely for performance reasons.

Comment: The problem you have is that either you need guarantees or you don't.  What it sounds like is you are ok if one or two messages are lost but not all of them?

Comment: Not true that messages are not persisted using async put. Async put accepts persistent messages. This feature decouples the ability to put a persistent message from the delivery of the status of the put. It is possible for the PUT to fail and the app not get the notification using this delivery method but WMQ *will* persist any message it gets asynchronously, if requested.

Comment: Also, the test case here is invalid.  Async put only makes sense if the app is streaming many messages.  Since the close is a blocking call, the test code will **never** see any benefit from async put.

Comment: Yes it's ok NOT to get notified if a Async put fails for a persistent message, I am hoping to reconcile losses using MQAsyncStatus and downstream consuming systems. But my question is, how do I do an Aysync put on a persisnt queue? When I send a large number of messages it takes 17 seconds for a persistent queue and 3 for non persistent, I would expect similar timings for both using Aysync put as I am not waiting for the message to be saved to the file system and the QueueManager to subsequently respond.  My feeling is that the Aync put is not working on the persistent queue.

Comment: In reality I am pushing through batches of messages, these can be circa 10,000 at a time.  Agreed that the test case does not reflect this.  So the close would be called after many messages have been sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up from the comments in the question, WMQ doesn't have a notion of a "persistent queue" (hence the reason I changed the title of the post).  The queue attribute for persistence does not in any way change how *the QMgr* treats the queue or any messages in it.  All that it does is to tell a program which persistence option to use if the programmer fails to explicitly set that value.  Whether any given message is persistent depends on whether the `MQMD` specified persistence when the message was first put to the queue.  Any queue can contain persistent and non-persistent messages in any combination.

Specifically, the code snippet int he post does not specify persistence using `message.setPersistence()` so it will inherit whatever the queue's default value is.    That in turn depends on the value inherited from the queue attribute.  *In no case does the queue attribute setting override an explicit setting from the app*.

So the performance difference that you are seeing is indeed most likely to reflect the setting of the queue's `DEFPSIST` attribute, but that does not mean that async puts are not working.  Remember that async puts do not in any way reduce the amount of time that it takes to put a message on the queue.  The QMgr has the same code path to persist a message whether the put is synchronous or not.  The difference is that *your app* no longer waits for the QMgr to finish its work.  It is entirely possible that when you call for an update of `MQAsyncStatus` that WMQ has not written *any* messages yet.  This is even more likely if they are all in a single unit of work because WMQ will not return the status for all the messages until after the `COMMIT` processing is complete.  Unless you call `COMMIT` explicitly, this happens when you close the queue.

You can verify this by repeating the `qMgr.getAsyncStatus()` call every second for a few seconds after the `COMMIT` or the `CLOSE`.  You should see that the first one returns no messages successfully put but that eventually you can account for all of them.

Incidentally, the question of whether the messages are persistent *should almost always be handled in your code*.  Message persistence is usually derived as a business requirement that is captured in the design of the application.  It is therefore the responsibility of the project manager and developer to insure that the requirement is met.  The only way to reliably make sure it is met is that the application calls `setPErsistence()` explicitly.  Otherwise, the application will use the value from the queue's `DEFPSIST` attribute to implicitly call `setPersistence()`.  So why bother to allow this kind of default in the API?  Because there are a few legitimate cases where persistence needs to be able to change *at run time*.  Writing the app to intentionally take the default value and reopen the queue after each unit of work accomplishes this.  In all other cases, persistence should be set in the program or in the managed objects.

Finally, if you are putting 10,000 messages under a single unit of work one other reason that you can get a response stating that no messages were successfully put is lack of log space or tunables not set to accommodate the load.  For example if `MAXUMSGS` is set to something less than 10,000 your entire transaction will roll back.  On the other hand, if `MAXUMSGS` is set correctly but the size and number of primary and secondary logs is insufficient to hold the amount of data in a transaction, then again the entire transaction will roll back.  You should play around a bit with the `COMMIT` interval because the optimal value depends on the size of the messages in relation to the size of the queue and log buffers.  Once you exceed the amount of data that can be optimized into a single write operation, additional messages actually decrease performance.  When people put 10,000 messages into a single unit of work it is hardly ever for performance but rather because this is their appropriate unit of recovery and the corresponding performance hit is secondary to the recovery requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If its ok to lose one or two messages you can add the messages to an internal send queue e.g.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor();

// build you message here

// add the message to be sent asynchronously.
service.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         queue.put(message, pmo);
    }
});
```

Any messages in the queue when the process dies is lost.

Comment: You are thinking WMQ v6.0 here, right? Because in v7.0 the native async PUT delegates this to the QMgr and does not create a race condition between the PUT and the CLOSE as does the sample above. I would think that in v7.0 and above a developer would be *much* better off using the native function but that this would be a good v6.0 workaround.

Comment: I am assuming you would close the connection only when shutting down the application.  Opening and closing connections can be more expensive than creating/sending messages.

Comment: Right, but if you dispatch several messages to a child thread and then issue a `CLOSE`, it creates a race condition in which the connection handle may be gone before all the messages are `PUT` by the child thread.  Although `CLOSE` is only issued once in the lifetime of the app, there needs to be some management of the child threads to prevent this condition.  Otherwise the method pretty much guarantees loss of at least one or two messages.

Comment: You can add the close as a job so there is no race condition. It just doesn't close immediately.